# Chromedriver pressing "ctrl + click" instead of normal "click"

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What i am doing is:

```
return element(by.xpath('//*/*[@id = "countyIds"]/option[contains(text(),"'+value+'")]')).click();
```

But i can see it does "ctrl + click" cause two values stay highlighted.

Html:

```
<select name="countyIds" id="countyIds" class="filter" multiple="">
       <option value="864">Banskobystrický kraj</option>
       <option value="821" selected="selected">Bratislavský kraj</option>
       <option value="892" selected="selected">Košický kraj</option>
       <option value="844">Nitriansky kraj</option>
       <option value="878">Prešovský kraj</option>
       <option value="834">Trenčiansky kraj</option>
       <option value="826">Trnavský kraj</option>
       <option value="852">Žilinský kraj</option>
</select>
```

You can see two `selected` values in second and third option. How to make normal "click"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Select object instead of clicking directly:

```
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

 // select the drop down list
 var countries = driver.FindElement(By.Name("countries"));
 //create select element object 
 var selectElement = new SelectElement(countries);

 //select by value
 selectElement.SelectByValue("844"); 
 // select by text
 selectElement.SelectByText("Prešovský kraj");
```

Comment: The problem with the above is that .SelectByValue and .SelectByText have the same behavior, they don't cause the selected element to be deselected, you need to call DeselectAll() first. However, sometimes webpages don't expect to have a select box with nothing selected.  I have a multi-select box where if I click as an actual user, it deselects the currently selected option and switches to the clicked option, but I can't achieve this behavior with ChromeDriver. Using DeselectAll() does not match what a user does.